# Oh... I think I made a mistake!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I'm many a game piece, many a stain,
>   Oh... I'm actually a word quite full of pain.
>
> I'm many an ocean, I'm a good student's marks!
>   Oh... I'm actually quite small, and found in gardens and parks.
>
> I'm many a trashcan, I'm many a part.
>   Oh... I'm actually partial, and unfair at heart.
>
> I'm a super popular drink, I'm a kid's cuddly friend!
>   Oh... you'll actually only use me after the end.

I feel like I did something wrong with this riddle.
Oh... what should I say now?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved... with some uh, gentle... hints in comments.

I'm many a game piece, many a stain,
Oh... I'm actually a word quite full of pain.

> Dice, Dyes, **D**ies

I'm many an ocean, I'm a good student's marks!
Oh... I'm actually quite small, and found in gardens and parks.

> Seas, AAAs, B**e**es

I'm many a trashcan, I'm many a part.
Oh... I'm actually partial, and unfair at heart.

> bins, bits, bi**a**s (thanks, **Kate Gregory**)

I'm a super popular drink, I'm a kid's cuddly friend!
Oh... you'll actually only use me after the end.

> beer, bear, bie**r** (thanks, **Kate Gregory**)

So, based on what those clues point to, the last line should be

> I feel like I did something wrong with this riddle.
>  Oh...**dear**

Additional comment by TheGreatEscaper:

> In hindsight, the stanzas should be in a different order. The four words, BEES, BIER, BIAS and DIES are each exactly one letter off from the nonsense string BIES. Taking the letters that are 'wrong', and in order of position in the string, you get DEAR, as intended.

Comment: On the right track! Keep in mind plurals, though.

Comment: try: bins, bits, bias and beer, bear, bier

Comment: @KateGregory seems good :)

Comment: Hey, the words you got from the riddle have gotta be important too, yknow... :P (Your first and second answers need an extra S, it's a bit finicky but would hopefully be signposted by the 4 letter answers to the last two)

Comment: I think if you take the four four-letter words for each stanza that are _actually_ the answer and take the right letters from them, you'll get something that can come after Oh ...!

Comment: oh "dear"? taking the first letter of the first answer, etc.

Comment: Mind if I edit to add an extra little touch?

Comment: I'm not sure I could have gotten there without brute forcing the combinations. I was expecting the answer to be a type of wordplay and not a... actually I'm not sure how to describe what I would have needed to do to derive the answer.